# Chartkick w/ Highcharts column_chart, specify visibility by series

Tags: ruby, highcharts, chartkick

On Highcharts it is possible to hide by default some selected series :

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
  "chart": {"type":"column","renderTo":"chart-1"},
  "categories":["10-2017","11-2017"],
  "series": [
    {"name":"Metric 1","data":[653.13,683.13]},
    {"name":"Metric 2","data":[6.87,6.87], "visible": false}
  ]})
```

However, I'm using Chartkick Ruby gem, and I cannot generate the code above.

```
<%= column_chart([
   { name:"Metric 1", data: { "10-2017" => 653.13, "11-2017" => 683.13 } }, 
   { name:"Metric 2", data: { "10-2017" => 6.87, "11-2017" => 6.87 }, visible: false }
]) %>
```

With this erb code snippet, the `visible: false` option is ignored.
Is there a way (maybe using the `library` parameter) to acheive this goal?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Chartkick Ruby, but check another approach of hiding one series on initialization in js: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8w5ycuah/1/.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it is probably a bug or an unimplemented issue with ChartKick.

I fixed it by manually running this JS code *after* initialization of `column_chart`:

```
var chart = Chartkick.charts["chart-1"].getChartObject();
chart.series[1].setVisible(false);
```

Verify if `chart-1` is the correct ID of your chart.